Can Docker Desktop load an image from an archived file?
I want to give a Docker image for my colleague to run on Docker Desktop, using as little CLI as possible.
I got a tarball archive using docker save (as documented on Docker Docs).
Docker Desktop only seems to search images online from the hub.
How can this be loaded on his Windows machine (equipped with WSL2)? Is it mandatory to use docker load in a console before using Docker Desktop?
